# Condition in subquery- select one value if subquery return 2 records else the actual value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `subquery` inside a big query which returns multiple values sometime and some time only one value. Below is my query and the returned values

```
select tran.customer_type from transaction_record tran where tran.TRANSACTION_ID=txn.id
```

> customer_type can be 2 records - "LP"  and "NA"

or

> customer_type can be 2 records - "SOEMTHING ELSE"  and "NA"

or

> customer_type can be 1 records - "NA"

Here my probem is if i have 2 records i have to print value without `NA` and if i have one record i have to print what ever be the value is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exectly efficient (2 queries), but it should work!

Inner query counts status, id combinatios per group and outer query
removes all NA statuses that have another record on same ID.

*Innermost query is just for table simulation (I like it more than create table, insert scripts).*

```
SELECT * FROM 
        (
                SELECT status, id, count(*)
                OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY 3 ) AS rn
                from (
                        SELECT 'NA' status, 1 id FROM dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 'LP' status, 1 id FROM dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 'NA' status, 2 id FROM dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 'SOEMTHING ELSE' status, 2 id FROM dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 'NA' status, 3 id FROM dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 'NA' status, 5 id FROM dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 'LP' status, 5 id FROM dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 'NA' status, 6 id FROM dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 'SOEMTHING ELSE' status, 6 id FROM dual
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 'NA' status, 22 id FROM dual
                    ))
    WHERE NOT (status = 'NA' AND rn=2)
```